# How can I utilize RegExp to check for string?

Tags: javascript, regex

Create a function that given a string, retains only the letters A-Z (upper and lowercase), 0-9 digits, and whitespace characters. Also, returns "Not a string!" if the entry type is not a string.

So far, I have:

```
function notAString(string) {
    var regex = new RegExp(`^(?=.*[A-Za-z])\d\s`, 'g');

    if (regex.test(string)) {
        return "String!";

    } else {
        return "Not a string!";
    }
}
```

I am only getting "Not a string!" returned, even if it is a string.

Comment: Use `if( typeof string !== 'string' ) { return "Not a string!"; }` at the start of your function. Also, I'd avoid using `string` for the name of the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure many people would agree with your definition of string! But based on the sequence you described, that would be `^[A-Za-z0-9\s]+$`

Check it out at https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your *RegEx* should be `^[A-Za-z 0-9]*$`:

**Where**

`^` asserts position at start of a line

`A-Z` matches a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z (index 90) (case sensitive)

`a-z` matches a single character in the range between a (index 97) and z (index 122) literally (case sensitive)

matches the space character

`0-9` matches a single character in the range between 0 (index 48) and 9 (index 57)  literally (case sensitive)

`*` quantifier — matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed

`$` asserts position at the end of a line

You can also use [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to simplify the solution like the following way:

```js
function notAString(string) {
  var regex = new RegExp(`^[A-Za-z 0-9]*$`, 'g');
  return regex.test(string)? 'String!' : 'Not a string!';
}
console.log(notAString('123 Test string')); // String!
console.log(notAString('Test@string'));     // Not a string!
```